# How To Continue Footnote Across Multiple Pages in a Pages Document?

Tags: macos, pages, formatting, word-processor

I have a footnote in a Pages document that I want to span across multiple pages. I essentially want the footnote to continue in the footnote margin on the next page, or possibly take up a whole page itself (it's a very large footnote).

What I want to do is essentially similar to this: http://blog.vlbteched.com/creating-footnote-continuation-notice/

However, I'm not even sure how to create a continuation notice for the footnote like you can do in Microsoft Word.

Here are some other examples of essentially what I want to do:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194087/automatic-insertion-of-contd-when-footnote-splits-across-pages
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297825/how-can-i-break-big-footnotes-using-an-automatic-continued-sign

I simply see no way to span a footnote across more than one page in my Pages document. When I reach the limit for the footnote on the current page, all the text I type afterwards seems to simply go "underneath" the bottom of the page, into some invisible "void". How can I make it so that the rest of the footnote can actually be visible on the next page(s) in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a hacky workaround for this problem. I found out that you can "piggyback" on another footnote on the next page by inserting whitespace above the footnote number. Then, you can type a number above it and make the number superscript and write something like:

> <sup>20 (footnote cont'd)</sup> footnote from previous page continues here...
> (this isn't an actual footnote, just some text which I changed the
> font for, and inserted above the below footnote)
>
> <sup>21</sup> new footnote begins here (this is an actual footnote which is
> linked to some text on the page)

This won't work for pages where there's not already a footnote there, but it worked in my case. Also, you'll still run into the problem of footnotes having a maximum length on a given page, but I was lucky enough to have two footnotes in short succession, so it was able to run across two pages, leaving only a single line at the bottom for the real footnote on the second page.

Again, this was not ideal, but it was a hacky workaround that happened to work for my situation.